# Scheduled builds in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cron, scheduler

I have a Jenkins scheduled build like this:

```
H 0 * * * command01
H 0 * * * command02
H 0 * * * command03
H 0 * * * command04
H 0 * * * command05
H 0 * * * command06
H 0 * * * command07
H 0 * * * command08
H 0 * * * command09
H 0 * * * command10
```

All commands work fine, except of command8, which doesn't start. Any idea why? Are there any limitations in Jenkins scheduler?

```
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)

Jenkins version 2.95
```

Thanks for any help and ideas.

Comment: The problem may lie in your command itself, which cannot be executed in the first place ? Otherwise, cannot see any reason why `7` and `9` would work, and not `8`.

Comment: Command is the same, only with different params. And it should at least create new failed build, but it doesn't.